# Venv home key in pyvenv.cfg

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

For continous integration purposes, I am using the following builtin py3.6 venv command (not to be confused with virtualenv) (see [pep 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/)).

```
python -m venv --system-site-packages --without-pip <ENVNAME>
```

I have found it to work great and I am getting an environment instantly.

BUT, .... venv produces a pyvenv.cfg file that looks like that:

```
home = absolute/path/to/prefix/of/interpreter/which/ran/venv
include-system-site-packages = true
version = <interpreter python version>
```

This file contains very crucial home key which refers to the original base python that this venv was created from. Very important to say that an **invalid** home key **crashes** python process which does not find its libraries in the base interpreter.

Now I want to deploy this "tested green" venv + its base python to the production machine. **I don't want to rebuild** it on the production system but just copying it to there.

Needless to say that the home absolute path created on the CI tool is not valid on the production machine, so I need to edit pyvenv.cfg file home key and everything is working like a charm.

This file manipulation is a step I really would like to avoid, as I would like to produce an artifact that just need to copied, activated and called (the standard way).

I tried to put %xyz%, $xyz and even configParser %(xyz)s on the original file but these do not resolve.
I also tried to use a relative path there, but the path is relative to the working directory and I don't want to force the production system to call my artifact from a pinned working directory.

**Is there a solution, other than the ugly pyvenv.cfg manipulation?**

Answer (score 2):

In windows:

Add the following code to `activate.bat` to dynamically generate `pyvenv.cfg` before each run.

```
type %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\python3\p3\scripts\pyvenv_tmp.cfg | powershell -Command "$input | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace \"CMDER_ROOT\", \"%CMDER_ROOT%\" }" > %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\python3\p3\pyvenv.cfg
```

pyvenv_tmp.cfg data：

```
home = CMDER_ROOT\vendor\python3
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.10.4.final.0
virtualenv = 20.14.0
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = CMDER_ROOT\vendor\python3
base-exec-prefix = CMDER_ROOT\vendor\python3
base-executable = CMDER_ROOT\vendor\python3\python3.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

According the specs in [Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) you do not need to activate the venv.

> You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path, so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual environment’s Python automatically.

Linux example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/usr/bin/python3.8 -m mypackage
```

MS Windows example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=venv/Lib/site-packages
c:/programs/python3.8/python.exe -m mypackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old, but found a working solution. Add the below to the `activate.bat` file.

```
:: Need to create pyvenv dynamically
set HOME=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python311
echo home = %HOME%>%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pyvenv.cfg
echo include-system-site-packages = false>>%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pyvenv.cfg
echo version = 3.11.1 = false>>%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pyvenv.cfg
echo executable = %HOME%\python.exe>>%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pyvenv.cfg
echo command = %HOME%\python.exe -m venv %VIRTUAL_ENV%>>%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pyvenv.cfg
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find common solution from the Django based project repositories in GitHub where they store all required modules in single text file **requirements.txt** rather than modules directory. When other people or production servers need them, they can download modules in **requirements.txt** from pypi.
So all you need is to generate requirements.txt file from your Yirtualenv and then submit this file to SCM.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can add links to this github repo, and demonstrate how to build such requirements file.